# Automatic authentication in desktop browser with WebAuthn

Tags: authentication, webauthn

At the Google I/O '18 a demo was shown in which a user authenticates at PayPal by just providing a fingerprint (see [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kGGMgEfSzMw) 24:40). This was done in a browser running on a Smartphone which has a fingerprint sensor and requires the browser to implement the WebAuthn standard. The fingerprint unlocks the private key which is used for a challenge-response authentication and which is stored on an authenticator.

As far as I understood user interaction (i.e. asking for a fingerprint) can be disabled by setting the `userVerification` argument to `discouraged` (see [w3.org](https://www.w3.org/TR/webauthn/#dom-userverificationrequirement-discouraged)). The user will be logged in automatically.

Can this flow also be implemented on a desktop browser without any extra hardware? Is there a default authenticator implemented in the browsers which could be used for that?

Concretely, I would like to do this:

- register a public/private key pair in the desktop browser via WebAuthn so that the private key cannot be accessed via JavaScript (e.g. to mitigate XSS attacks)
- every time data is send to a server sign that data via the WebAuthn API with the private key stored in the "default" authenticator without requiring user interaction

Comment: My password manager logs me in automatically to PayPal on my desktop browser.

Comment: I think this is far more or a programmign question than a security question since you are looking to manipulate WebAuthn

Answer (score 1):

> Can this flow also be implemented on a desktop browser without any extra hardware? Is there a default authenticator implemented in the browsers which could be used for that?

Chrome and probably most browsers can generate a public-private key pair and use it for authentication. However, the security of this key without being protected by a dedicated hardware as in the case of the phone is very dubious at best.

The preferred solution would be to use an USB token such as YubiKey. Most of these do require interaction, namely pressing a button on the token, to prevent malware from using it without the users knowledge, but you may be able to find one that does not, or alternatively you may be able to find one that allows you to modify its firmware and disable this requirement.

Comment: Can Chrome manage key pairs without AddOns? Firefox can not. Well, most browsers is misleading. On desktop only Firefox and Chrome support WebAuthn and only Mobile Chrome.

Comment: Chrome70 now supports publicKey authenticators like biometry sensors on mobile phones and laptops.

Comment: @Spock how? I couldn't find that feature.

Comment: @cslotty I'm sorry I just saw your question now. Look up WebAuthn, I have implemented fingerprint/face unlock authentication on our company website and it works wonderfully.

Comment: @Spock I have read pretty much anything that can be found on WebAuthN! :-)  But it seemed that Chrome only supported USB keys. Now you're telling me fingerprints etc work - so I'll give it a try - thanks.

Comment: What about without hardware, including fingerprint readers?

We store client side credentials all the time (Session IDs, Refresh Tokens, Credential Manager). Even a software backed Private Key Signing is better than a Javascript accessible Shared Secret.